# Array as parameter is undefined

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Just tried this code in JSFiddle (learning JS atm):

```
var checkArrayForDuplicates = new function(arrayToCheck, content) {
    alert(arrayToCheck);
}

var numbers = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5);    
checkArrayForDuplicates(numbers, 5);
```

But arrayToCheck (numbers) is always undefined inside the function. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function definition is not correct, change to:

```
var checkArrayForDuplicates = function(arrayToCheck, content) {
    alert(arrayToCheck);
}
```

You have put `new` in your definition in front of the function name, and this is not the right syntax to use with `new`.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the stuff I have to deal with when moving from Java and C# to JS.

Comment: @mosquito87 You are welcome, glad I could help. I worked with both C# and Java and still, but JavaScript *(in my opinion)* is much more powerful and flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `new` word. It should just be:

```
= function () {}
```